# TE_READONLY in styledtextctrl not working

Tags: wxpython, readonly

I am working on a editor with styledtextctrl, the editor has to be read-only for the users, but with TE_READONLY defined, the editor still editable, the snippet is as following:

text_ctrl = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, -1, wx.Point(0,0), wx.Size(150, 90),
                        wx.DOUBLE_BORDER | wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_RICH2 | wx.TE_DONTWRAP )

I tried SetReadOnly(True), with which python code cannot write to the editor either, I need to show the user text with different style, but the user cannot edit the text.

Any suggestion is appreciated！

Answer (score 0):

The method SetReadOnly has a capital O.

```
text_ctrl.SetReadOnly(True)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's with capital O in my code, just wrote it wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can **toggle editable mode** before and after writing to it as in:

```
text.SetEditable(True)
text.AddText("some text")
text.SetEditable(False)
```

Comment: That's a way out, thanks. But I have a lot of different styles for the text and I need to change the text style in real time, if I set the switch on/off all the time, the code would be very cumbersome and it's easy to make mistakes. Is there any other simple way for this?

Comment: @Y.Yuan You can always wrap it in another function, that would prevent repetitive code. As for a simpler alternative, i don't know any.